# How to perform pivot on spark dataframe using spark-scala?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below one is the input Dataframe.

```
+----------+------------+
|sensortype|sensorstatus|
+----------+------------+
|Sensor1   |offline     |
|Sensor1   |offline     |
|Sensor1   |online      |
|Sensor2   |offline     |
|Sensor2   |offline     |
|Sensor3   |online      |
+----------+------------+
```

I want to change the above dataFrame as shown below,

```
+----------+-------+------+-----+
|sensortype|offline|online|total|
+----------+-------+------+-----+
|Sensor2   |2      |0     |2    |
|Sensor3   |0      |1     |1    |
|Sensor1   |2      |1     |3    |
+----------+-------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the required result using pivot and aggregation functions using spark-scala.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
  // Sample dataframe
  val df = Seq(
    ("Sensor1", "offline"),
    ("Sensor1", "offline"),
    ("Sensor1", "online"),
    ("Sensor2", "offline"),
    ("Sensor2", "offline"),
    ("Sensor3", "online")
  ).toDF("sensortype", "sensorstatus")

  df.groupBy("sensortype")
    .pivot("sensorstatus").agg(count("sensorstatus"))
    // Replace null by 0 in columns - offline and online
    .na.fill(0, Seq("offline", "online"))
    .withColumn("total", 'offline + 'online)
    .show(false)

+----------+-------+------+-----+
|sensortype|offline|online|total|
+----------+-------+------+-----+
|Sensor2   |2      |0     |2    |
|Sensor3   |0      |1     |1    |
|Sensor1   |2      |1     |3    |
+----------+-------+------+-----+
```

Comment: I am getting error in this line -> ".withColumn("total", 'offline + 'online)"